# "value >> is not a member of" compilation error

Tags: scala, implicit

I have the following code:

```
import java.io.{File, PrintWriter}                                                                                            

import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._                                                                                  
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.browser.JsoupBrowser                                                                     
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.browser.JsoupBrowser.JsoupElement                                                        
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.model.{ElementNode, Node}                                                                

object ConvertHTMLToCSV extends App {                                                                                         
  val browser = JsoupBrowser()                                                                                                
  val doc = browser.parseFile("my-doc.html")               
  doc >> "h3"
    .
    .
    . 
}
```

I am getting the following compilation error:

```
Error:(11, 7) value >> is not a member of ConvertHTMLToCSV.browser.DocumentType
  doc >> "h3"
```

I am trying to implement an [example given for the Scala Scraper library](https://github.com/ruippeixotog/scala-scraper#content-extraction).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like

```
implicit def cssQueryAsExtractor[E <: Element](cssQuery: String)
: HtmlExtractor[E, ElementQuery[E]] = HtmlExtractor.forQuery(cssQuery)
```

from [`ImplicitConversions`](https://github.com/ruippeixotog/scala-scraper/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/net/ruippeixotog/scalascraper/dsl/ImplicitConversions.scala#L9) is not in the implicit scope. I assume that you should have at least one import that looks something like that:

```
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.dsl.DSL._
// or
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.dsl.ImplicitConversions._
```

Or maybe it's one of those (mentioned in the readme):

> The DSL provides several contentExtractor and contentParser instances, which were imported before with `DSL.Extract._` and `DSL.Parse._`.